# Mysql Handlers: Possible to run local Ubuntu script on table change?

Tags: mysql

Does mysql support some kind of table listeners? It would be nice if I could tell mysql to trigger external script with some options when table is changed.

For example i have some script or daemon running on background and when mysql table is changed
script is called script -opt1 opt2 etc

Is it possible? Is there anything like that already?

The problem is, that i need to renew cache on my app when mysql tables are changed.

Thanks ;)

Comment: What does not suffice with the 'normal' triggers calling a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call up any piece of code from inside a trigger, as suggested by Bobby; this can be a stored procedure or an external function. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html) for how to create external functions (it looks a bit fraught to me though).